# TypeError: plugin is not a function

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, node-modules

```
Failed to compile.

TypeError: plugin is not a function
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
WARNING in ./node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/auth.esm.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from 'D:\Java-Script-Lectures\Javascript-Projects\React-Seafood-Market\node_modules\@firebase\auth\dist\ [synthetic:es6\promise\promise] ' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\Java-Script-Lectures\Javascript-Projects\React-Seafood-Market\node_modules\@firebase\auth\dist\ [synthetic:es6\promise\promise] '

WARNING in ./node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/auth.esm.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from 'D:\Java-Script-Lectures\Javascript-Projects\React-Seafood-Market\node_modules\@firebase\auth\dist\ [synthetic:es6\util\arrayiterator] ' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\Java-Script-Lectures\Javascript-Projects\React-Seafood-Market\node_modules\@firebase\auth\dist\ [synthetic:es6\util\arrayiterator] '

WARNING in ./node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/auth.esm.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from 'D:\Java-Script-Lectures\Javascript-Projects\React-Seafood-Market\node_modules\@firebase\auth\dist\ [synthetic:es6\util\makeiterator] ' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\Java-Script-Lectures\Javascript-Projects\React-Seafood-Market\node_modules\@firebase\auth\dist\ [synthetic:es6\util\makeiterator] '

WARNING in ./node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/auth.esm.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from 'D:\Java-Script-Lectures\Javascript-Projects\React-Seafood-Market\node_modules\@firebase\auth\dist\ [synthetic:util\defineproperty] ' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\Java-Script-Lectures\Javascript-Projects\React-Seafood-Market\node_modules\@firebase\auth\dist\ [synthetic:util\defineproperty] '  

WARNING in ./node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/auth.esm.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from 'D:\Java-Script-Lectures\Javascript-Projects\React-Seafood-Market\node_modules\@firebase\auth\dist\ [synthetic:util\global] ' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\Java-Script-Lectures\Javascript-Projects\React-Seafood-Market\node_modules\@firebase\auth\dist\ [synthetic:util\global] '

WARNING in ./node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/auth.esm.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from 'D:\Java-Script-Lectures\Javascript-Projects\React-Seafood-Market\node_modules\@firebase\auth\dist\ [synthetic:util\polyfill] ' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\Java-Script-Lectures\Javascript-Projects\React-Seafood-Market\node_modules\@firebase\auth\dist\ [synthetic:util\polyfill] '

ERROR in ./src/css/style.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[2]!./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/css/style.css)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
TypeError: plugin is not a function
    at LazyResult.run (D:\Java-Script-Lectures\Javascript-Projects\React-Seafood-Market\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:197:24)
    at D:\Java-Script-Lectures\Javascript-Projects\React-Seafood-Market\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:110:37
    at LazyResult.asyncTick (D:\Java-Script-Lectures\Javascript-Projects\React-Seafood-Market\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:124:15)
    at D:\Java-Script-Lectures\Javascript-Projects\React-Seafood-Market\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:150:20
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at LazyResult.async (D:\Java-Script-Lectures\Javascript-Projects\React-Seafood-Market\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:147:27)
    at LazyResult.then (D:\Java-Script-Lectures\Javascript-Projects\React-Seafood-Market\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:72:21)

webpack compiled with 1 error and 6 warnings
```

**Above is the error that I get when I run my code on localhost.**

```
import Rebase from 're-base';
import Firebase from 'firebase';

const firebaseApp = Firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "AIzaSyDtF8e7XcIYu5FKDb69RVMtNOPdgHwvz34",
    authDomain: "catch-of-the-day-jai-marothiya.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://catch-of-the-day-jai-marothiya-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
});

const base = Rebase.createClass(firebaseApp.database());

// This is a named export
export {firebaseApp};

//this is default export
export default base;
```

**This one is my base.js file which have firebase oath section**

What will I do any command that I need to run or why I'll get this error.I reinstall node modules also follow others solution for this problem but still problem is not solved.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share your `./src/css/style.css` file?